# How can I remove hair dye stains from a porcelain sink?

Tags: bathroom, cleaning, sink

Anyone have any suggestions about how to do this?  I've tried Comet, bleach and windex, all applied with plenty of elbow grease, but the stains aren't budging.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You may have to essentially grind it off with polishing compounds meant for glass lenses. The initial cut will remove the stain, but cloud the finish. Progressively finer cuts will restore the finish. If it's down in any fine pores, that portion will never come out. Before doing that, try magic eraser. It's a bit like a cross between very fine sandpaper and a fine scrub brush (melanine foam).

Comment: bczwork's comment should actually be an answer.

Comment: If he makes it one, I'll accept it...

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a Magic Eraser. That did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Acetone is an effective solvent for many household stains.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to a beauty supply shop. There are commercial hairdye removers that beauty shops use. The type you need will vary with the type of dye that caused the stain. It may be helpful if you can bring the offending product with you. This is a scary thought but one site suggested using more hair dye to remove the stain. The theory being that the solvent in fresh dye will soften the old stain.